# Showing a subset of vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Studying “Linear Algebra Step By Step” p. 217, I am trying to understand why my solution is wrong.

> Example 3.15
>
> Let $V$ be the vector space of continuous functions defined on the real line. Let $u=\cos(x)$, $v=\sin(x)$ and $w=2$ be vectors in V.
> Show that the vectors u, v and w are linearly independent.

I came to the conclusion that set is not linearly independent because I found non-zero scalars $x=2$, $y=1$ and $z=\frac{-1}{2}$ such that the equation

$$2\cos(0)+1\sin(0)+(\frac{-1}{2})2=0$$

is true.

Could someone give me some insight?

Comment: The same scalars would have to work for all values of $x$, not just $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved correctly that the function$$x\mapsto2\times\cos(x)+1\times\sin(x)+\left(-\frac12\right)\times2$$takes the value $0$ at $0$. And then what? At, say, $\frac\pi4$, it *doesn't* take the value $0$. In other words, it is *not* the null function.

Answer (score 1):

Formal Proof:

Suppose $$a \sin x+b \cos x+2c\equiv0 \tag1$$ Which means , the above equation vanishes for all $x$

Differentiation yields $$a \cos x-b \sin x \equiv0 \tag2$$  Put $x=0$ to see $a=0$

Differentiate  $(2)$ again and set $x=0$ to see $b=0$. Now $(1)$ implies $c=0$ too, concluding, the set $\{\sin x, \cos x, 2\}$ is independent

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\cos x+b \sin x+2c=0$ (for  all $x$). Put $x=0$ to get $a+2c=0$. Put $x=\pi /2$ to get $b+2c=0$. Put $x =\pi /4$ to get $\frac {a+b} {\sqrt 2} +2c=0$. It is easy to show that these equations give $a=b=c=0$ so the functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

To show linear dependence we should find $a$,$b$ and $c$ which work for any $x$

$$a\cdot \cos(x)+b\cdot \sin(x)+c\cdot 2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: if
$$a\cos x+b\sin x+2c=0\tag{1}$$
identically, then by replacing $x$ by $-x$,
$$a\cos x-b\sin x+2c=0\tag{2}$$
identically. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get both $a\cos x+2c=0$ and $b\sin x=0$
identically. As neither $\cos x$ nor $\sin x$ are constant functions,
those imply $a=c=b=0$.